# Accessing static interface properties like abstract static interface properties

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, c#-8.0, c#-11.0

Why does the compiler give me a *CS0704 Cannot do non-virtual member lookup in 'T' because it is a Type parameter* error when I try to call `T.Property()` in the `GetProp<T>()` method, yet it doesn't complain about accessing `T.SomeProperty()`?

```
int GetProp<T>() where T : ISomeInterface
{
    var property = T.Property();
    var someProp = T.SomeProperty();
    return 99;
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    static int Property() { return 99; }
    abstract static int SomeProperty();
}

public class SomeClass1 : ISomeInterface
{
    public static int SomeProperty() { return 2; }
}

public class SomeClass2 : ISomeInterface
{
    public static int SomeProperty() { return 3; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there are two different language concepts in action here.

The first one - `static int Property() { return 99; }` was introduced in C# 8 and it is not actually a part of the interface contract, it is part of the interface implementation (NB!). This is called [default implementations in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods) and it allows to specify static fields, methods, properties, indexers, and events in interfaces:

> The syntax for an interface is extended to permit
>
> - ...
> - member declarations that declare static fields, methods, properties, indexers, and events;
> - ...

> Interfaces may not contain instance state. While static fields are now permitted, instance fields are not permitted in interfaces. Instance auto-properties are not supported in interfaces, as they would implicitly declare a hidden field.

Which allows to achieve the following goal:

> Static and private methods permit useful refactoring and organization of code used to implement the interface's public API.

And you can access it by the interface name:

```cs
var property = ISomeInterface.Property();
```

The second one - `static abstract int SomeProperty();` comes with C# 11 and is called [abstract static members in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces) and it allows to enforce implementation of some static method in the concrete type, so you can access it only via concreate type, i.e. the `var someProp = T.SomeProperty();`.

Comment: I'm struggling with that. So either first one (C# 8) allow me to access `IFoo.StaticProp` or second one (C#11) access it via concreate type `Foo.StaticProp` ? There is no solution to have the same static property, defined in an interface (`IFoo`) and initialized in an implementing class (`Foo`) to be accessed both either via `IFoo` or `Foo` ?

Comment: @TRex not sure what is the goal. Static abstract methods are not instance ones, what should happen if you write `IFoo.StaticProp`? What implementation should be invoked. You can declare `static virtual StaticProp ...`, then you will be able to access it via generic indirection with `void Do<T>() where T:IFoo => T.StaticProp` and `Do<IFoo>`/`Do<Foo>`. Without more explanation what do you actually need - it is hard to tell.

Comment: Lets say `IFoo` define a `static (abstract/virtual/_) int Sint {get; set;}`. `Foo : IFoo` class would initialize `IFoo.Sint = 0;` at `ctor` for example. I'd want to be able to get `Sint` value either via `IFoo.Sint` or `Foo.Sint`.

Comment: @TRex why exactly do you want it? Also why foo class would initialize static property in ctor?

Comment: In my case, I'm using .Net D.I. in my library, `IFoo` would expose `static IServiceProvider` property, witch w'd be initialized by `Foo` via D.I. at `ctor` time when called by consuming project. I'm working with that, using `IFoo.Services` when needed. It was more curiosity while developing if I could access same `Services` via `IFoo` and/or `Foo`. For now I'm using another (same name for convenience) static property in `Foo` that refer directly to `IFoo.Services` in `get/set`. Though I don't really need it in/from `Foo`, it was more a doable or not question.